# Naming an array using a variable

Tags: arrays, vba, loops, excel, excel-2010

Is it possible to name an array variable using a different variable?  For example, if I define variable "i" as an integer with a value equal to the number of columns I've used it a sheet:

```
Sub varNameTest

    Dim i, j, As Integer
    i = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
    ...
```

Is it possible to then establish "i" number of arrays named something like myArray1 through i?  Possibly something like:

```
For j = 1 to i
    Dim (myArray & j())
Next i
```

Though this example immediately above is incorrect syntax, I'm just trying illustrate what I'm trying to do.

edit:  so to be more clear, using the above example, say I have 4 sheets in a workbook.  The variable i would then be 4, and I would have some code that generates myArray1(), myArray2(), myArray3() and myArray4().

Comment: AFAIK, I don't think so. What you can do is create an array instead of creating the variable at runtime.

Comment: Your edit doesn't really clarify the question.  It might help to explain what you then want to do with these "named" arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of arrays (though your question is a little unclear..)

```
Sub MyArrays()

Dim arrays()
Dim arr
Dim i, j

    i = 5 'e.g.
    ReDim arrays(1 To i)

    For j = 1 To i
        arr = Array()
        ReDim arr(1 To j)
        arrays(j) = arr
    Next j
    'reference an array by its position in "arrays"
    Debug.Print UBound(arrays(3))

End Sub
```

Comment: Your edit doesn't really clarify why it's important to create named variables: typically this is not required (besides not really being possible in VBA) and there are better approaches to acheive the same end.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
Dim i(5) As Integer
```

In VBA you can then access elements from `i(0)` to `i(5)`.

---

Based on your edited question, the answer is no. You must explicitly define each variable in your code.

The other option would be to write code that writes your code - a form of code generation. Effectively that lets you write very long and complex code by repeating code "templates". But I don't think this would help in your case.