# passing string as array name in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba

I want to pass array name as string.

```
 Dim i as Integer
 Dim arName as String
 Dim ar1(10) as Integer 'array of 10 elements
 Dim ar2(10) as Integer
 Dim ar3(10) as Integer

 for i = 1 to 3
     arName ="ar" & i
     arName(1)=34 ' I want 34 in every 1st element of all three arrays 
 Next i
 End sub
```

I am doing this as Array practice.
How to pass Array Name as string is my question

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27994108/naming-an-array-using-a-variable

Answer (score 1):

Just create a single multi-dimensional array

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim arr(1 To 3, 1 To 10) As Integer
For i = 1 To 3
    arr(i, 1) = 34
Next
```

Comment: No that is not what I intended. I want to check if array name can be passed as string like ar1(x,y)  ar2(x,y) where ar1 ="ar" & i (i coming from iteration.)

Comment: No, you cannot do that in VBA.